# robotframework: [ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user

Tags: robotframework

i´m trying to figure out an error message from robotframework (Jenkins 2.289.2). It is the error:

> [ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user.

I try set set up some robot test cases with python (3.92) on Linux (OpenSuse). I have a simple testprogramm in python which is called by a shell (which in turn is configured in the robot pipeline):

> #!/bin/bash
> python -m robot   /home/john/robotest/fuenf.robot

in "**fuenf.robot**" i make a simple call to a member function of a class which i instantiated in the Library section

> Socket Call
>
> ```
> ${ausgabe} =    test Prog
> ```

The **python** code sniplet:

```
def test_Prog(self):
    print("Test ....   test     ....      test  .....    test   ...     ")
    return
```

which is working when called from python interpreter
The robot **pipeline** is:

> ```
> pipeline {
>     agent any 
>     stages {
>         stage('Stage 1') {
>             steps {
>                 sh "/bin/bash /home/john/robotest/calltest05.bash"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

When i look into the jenkins **pipeline step** output:

> hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 253  at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.handleExit(DurableTaskStep.java:659)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.check(DurableTaskStep.java:605)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.run(DurableTaskStep.java:549)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
> .run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

The **console output** gives:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TestPipelineParallel
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stage 1)
[Pipeline] sh
+ /bin/bash /home/john/robotest/calltest05.bash
[ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 253
Finished: FAILURE
```

I can try what i like, in every combination, i get the error:

[ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user.

I have no idea why this is happening or where to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

> - /bin/bash /home/john/robotest/calltest05.bash

returned 253 and Jenkins is expecting 0.

If that shell script calls some process `kill` it may cause the `Execution stopped by user.` error.

Comment: the shall has only one command "python -m robot  /.../fuenf.robot" and i checked the code (which is simple, there are no return or exit commands).

Comment: And if i call the shellscript, with only this command, it gives the same Error. Helio, i´ve found another exit which would be active when the input parameter were not correct. I commented it and now the Error dissapeared.

Comment: Funny Helio, i´ve read this hint several times yesterday, but when you wrote this, what i knew before, i seriously checked my code again :-))